# Create Table with LINQ To SQL / SQL CE

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

I am new to SQL and I tried create a table with LINQ To SQL.

First I create DataContext object:

```
        const string connStr = @"Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.sdf";
        _dc = new Spiri_SQL_CE_DB(connStr);
```

And the I try create DB table with this method:

```
public void CreateUserTab(string nick)
{        
    string sqlCdm = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "CREATE TABLE {0} (Nick nvarchar(30) PRIMARY KEY, AzetID nvarchar(30), RpText nvarchar(300), Your bit, Sing nvarchar(30), Time DateTime, OriginalTxt nvarchar(300))",nick);

    _dc.ExecuteCommand(sqlCdm);

    _dc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**1.**

First problem is that I use this method, create table and close app. But new created table is not in database.

I think that changes which I do on database are not saved DB. If I check db file in server explorer I don’t see new db table.

**2.**
And second problem is.

For example I have class which represent DB table, here is it:

```
[Table]
public class User
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string Nick { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string AzetId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public String RpText { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public bool Your { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Sing { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string OriginalTxt { get; set; }
}
```

I know that is possible mapping SQL table on CLR class Tabel. It’s possible create DB table (with specific name) with this class?

I would like omited SQL command in my code, is it possible create db table from CLR object?

**3.**

And the last question is:

Scenario is:

I have SQL compact DB file, it consist one table User1 type of `Table<User>`, I generate with SqlMetal *dbml file.

Then I from code create another tables User2, User3 ... UserN.

Close app.

It possible have access to db table User2 ... UserN? Or I must create another dbml file ?

Answer (score 0):

1: Use a full path to the sdf file in your connection string to avoid confusion about the location of the file.

2: Yes, you can call _dc.CreateDatabase, and your tables will be created. (The class must be included as a Table object in your DataContext

3: Why not create the required code in a .cs file instead?